# Sphinx 4: recognize wav with words pronounced with short pause

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I am new to Sphinx 4 and trying to make simple digits recognition application.
I have set of wavs with 3 digits pronounced with short pause (like one_five_nine.wav) for test.
The problem is that recognition of file stops after first digit found, so I have only "one" as output for one_five_nine.wav.

Here is my front-end config

```
<component name="epFrontEnd16k" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.FrontEnd">
    <propertylist name="pipeline">
        <item>audioFileDataSource</item>
        <item>dataBlocker </item>
        <item>speechClassifier </item>
        <item>speechMarker </item>
        <item>nonSpeechDataFilter </item>
        <item>preemphasizer </item>
        <item>windower </item>
        <item>fft </item>
        <item>melFilterBankFor16k</item>
        <item>dct </item>
        <item>liveCMN </item>
        <item>featureExtraction </item>
    </propertylist>
</component>
```

and code

```
    Recognizer recognizer = (Recognizer) cm.lookup("recognizer");
    recognizer.allocate();

    AudioFileDataSource dataSource = (AudioFileDataSource) cm.lookup("audioFileDataSource");

    File folder = new File(testDataSetDirectory);
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        // retrive URL
        URL audioURL = null;
        try {
            audioURL = fileEntry.toURL();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // configure the audio input for the recognizer
        dataSource.setAudioFile(audioURL, null);

        Result result = recognizer.recognize();         
        String recognizedText = result != null ? result.getBestFinalResultNoFiller() : "null";

        // print
        System.out.println(fileEntry.getName() + ":\t" + recognizedText);
    }
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to invoke recognizer in a loop:

```
 Result result;
 while(true) {
    result = recognizer.recognize();         
    if (result == null)
         break;
 }
```